# woocommerce product import not working in backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing one problem when i clicked on import button(backend) in woocommerce product menu it gives me error and that is this page isn't working 
i am also try from tools->import->WooCommerce products (CSV). 
I have also increase memory limit in php.ini file but i am facing same problem into it. I want to import products in my woocommerce store

[image: woocommerce product import problem]

Comment: After sometimes, again you import the file. because you try to import file many times.

Comment: i am trying this from last two days

Answer (score 1):

I had same Issue and after several attempts that failed, I finally fixed it.

1. Temporarily changed themes to twenty seventeen. Then imported the products

   **OR**
2. Try saving the permalinks under *Settings > Permalinks >* Save and try the import again?

   **OR**
3. Check if the theme has a demo importer, if yes, disable it and that should work.

Comment: Kudos! 
3rd Solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the memory,

Put the line on wp-config.php file,

```html
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Now, you can try to import the file

Comment: Hi priynka I've try by adding a code that you share with me but problem is not resolved.

Comment: when i am click on import button from product menu it gives me error message after 10sec i.e This page isn’t working

Comment: Then, try to again re-install plugin and test it

Comment: woocommerce plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Let's sum up what you can do if WooCommerce import not working. Most often, import issues occur because some plugins or themes turn out to be incompatible with the system. So a common recommendation would be to disable plugins to find out which one causes a conflict and temporarily switch to the WordPress default theme

I found another importer by theme when I deactivate that importer the problem was solved.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Adding links and screenshots might be helpful.